# Jquery show hide list items after nth item, not working with ajax loaded content

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I want to hide ul li items when they are more than 3, and display "view more" button to expand and show more li items. I am using the following jquery code which is working fine with the static content, but not when the content is loaded dynamically with ajax.

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    $('ul.categorylist').each(function () {  
  $(this).find('li').filter(':gt(2)').filter("li[class!='More']").slideToggle(500);
        if (($(this).children().size()) > 4) {
            $(this).append('<li class="More"><a href="Javascript:void(0);">View More...</a></li>').find('li:last').click(function () {            $(this).parent().children().filter(':gt(3)').filter("li[class!='More']").slideToggle(800);
                if ($(this)[0].innerHTML.indexOf("View More...") == -1)
                    $(this)[0].innerHTML = $(this)[0].innerHTML.replace("View Less...", "View More...");
                else
                    $(this)[0].innerHTML = $(this)[0].innerHTML.replace("View More...", "View Less...");
            });
        }
    });
});
```

This is the angularjs controller I'm using

```
  .controller('SubCategoriesCtrl', ['$scope', '$routeParams', '$filter', '$rootScope', '$http', '$location', 'SubCategories', function ($scope, $routeParams, $filter, $rootScope, $http, $location, SubCategories) {

        var cat1 = "";
        var cat2 = "";
        var url = window.location.pathname.split('/');
        for(var i=0; i<url.length; i++) {
            if(url[i].length > 0)
            {
                if(i==1)
                    cat1 = url[i];
                if(i==2)
                    cat2 = url[i];
            }
        }
        if(cat1 != "aboutus" && cat1 != "contactus" && cat1 != "termsofuse" && cat1 != "privacypolicy" && cat1 != "sitemap") {
            SubCategories.customGETLIST("", {"query": cat1}).then(function(subcategories) {
                fixLiElements();
                $scope.subcategories = subcategories;

                //console.log($scope.subcategories);
            }, function(error) {
                console.log("we had an error here while loading sub categories.." + error);
            });
        }

  }])
```

And this is how I'm calling it in page

```
    <div ng-repeat="c in subcategories | filter:{ categorylevel: 1 }" class="category-list-container">
        <ul ng-repeat="cat in subcategories | filter:{ categorylevel: 2 } | orderBy:'name'" class="catlist">
            <h3 class="CatPCat2Name">[[cat.name]]</h3>

                <li ng-repeat="catt in subcategories | filter:{ parentcategoryid: cat.id} | filter:{ categorylevel: 3 } | orderBy:'name'">
                    <a ng-href="/[[c.slug]]/[[cat.slug]]/[[catt.slug]]">[[catt.name]]</a>
                </li>
                <li ng-repeat="catt in subcategories | filter:{ parentcategoryid: cat.id} | filter:{ categorylevel: 4 } | orderBy:'name'">
                    <a ng-href="/[[c.slug]]/[[cat.slug]]/[[catt.slug]]">[[catt.name]]</a>
                </li>


        </ul>
    </div>
```

I've tried both with ajaxStop() and calling it on ajax success, but failed.

Kindly help where I'm doing wrong, and where should I use this jquery script ??

Answer (score 1):

when content is loaded dynamically using jQuery, they won't be binded to ul li items. So your code isn't working for the content loaded using jQuery. For that to work, you need to use jQuery's `ajaxStop()` event in case content is loaded using ajax.

e.g.

```
function yourfunction(){
    $('ul.categorylist').each(function () {  
          $(this).find('li').filter(':gt(2)').filter("li[class!='More']").slideToggle(500);
            if (($(this).children().size()) > 4) {
                $(this).append('<li class="More"><a href="Javascript:void(0);">View More...</a></li>').find('li:last').click(function () {            $(this).parent().children().filter(':gt(3)').filter("li[class!='More']").slideToggle(800);
                    if ($(this)[0].innerHTML.indexOf("View More...") == -1)
                        $(this)[0].innerHTML = $(this)[0].innerHTML.replace("View Less...", "View More...");
                    else
                        $(this)[0].innerHTML = $(this)[0].innerHTML.replace("View More...", "View Less...");
                });
            }
        });
    }
}

//call ready event to bind for the content when is loaded
$(document).ready(function() {yourfunction(); });

//call ajaxStop event to bind for the content when ajax call is made
$(document).ajaxStop(function() {yourfunction(); });
```

Comment: I'm not confident you need to bind anything here; it's just selectors.  If it's in the DOM, jQuery will find it.  Binding is a problem when elements are added after ajax that weren't there on load and need events attached (binded) to them.  There's no user events (eg: clicks) to listen for here.

Comment: these suggestions are perfect, but unfortunately this is not working for me, may be there is something what I'm unable to explain, but thanks anyway. I've also updated my question.

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming the `li` elements aren't there yet with ajax loaded content so the function probably fires too early.  Try putting all of the code inside the document ready function inside of a named function and calling it on both document ready and ajax success.

```
function fixLiElements(){
  $('ul.categorylist').each(function () { ... }
}

$(document).ready(fixLiElements);

//inside ajax object, after elements are added to DOM.
success : fixLiElements()
```

Comment: Thanks really for your suggestions, but its not working for me. I have also updated my question to make it more clear.